# Transforming list to multiple nested maps

Tags: java

I get a List like this, one Object per row holding plain strings:

```
Vehicle, Name, Property, Value
------------------------------
Car, VW, Tires, 4
Car, VW, Doors, 4
Car, Porsche, Tires, 4
Car, Porsche, Doors, 2
Car, Porsche, Color, Red
Plane, A340, Tires, 12
Plane, A340, Color, White
Plane, A750, Doors, 6
Forklift, ABC345, Color, Orange
... and so on
```

I want to return that as JSON in the form of:

```
{ 
"Car" : {
     "VW":{ "Tires" : "4", "Doors": "4"},
     "Porsche":{ "Tires" : "4", "Doors": "2" }
     },
"Plane":{
     "A340":{ "Tires" : "12", "Color" : "White" },
     "A750":{ "Doors" : "6" }
     },
"Forklift" : {
     "ABC345": { "Color" : "Orange" }
     }
}
```

I tried using a weird

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>>
```

but to be honest, I don't know how to set this up correctly. When I iterate over the list and write to the HashMap, Property and Value always get overwritten, so my result looks like this:

```
{ 
"Car" : {
     "Porsche":{ "Tires" : "4" }
     },
"Plane":{
     "A750":{ "Doors" : "6" }
     },
"Forklift" : {
     "ABC345": { "Color" : "Orange" }
     }
}
```

I'm fairly new to Java and don't know how the handle this kind of nested Maps.

I mean, asking for being pampered is a bit embarrassing, but maybe someone can show me how to do this in a correct way.

Edit: here how I add values, I haven't pasted this part of the code as I don't know HOW to check and decide what to do.

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>> vehiclesData = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>>();

for( VehicleReportRow vehicleReportRow : unpreparedRows ){
    String vehicle = vehicleReportRow.getVehicle();
    String name = vehicleReportRow.getName();
    String property = vehicleReportRow.getProperty();
    String value = vehicleReportRow.getValue();

    //the most inner dataset
    HashMap<String,String> propAndVal = new HashMap<String, String>();
   propAndVal.put(property, value);

    //the middle dataset            
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>> nameToProps = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>>();
    nameToProps.put(name, propAndVal);

    //and finally the outer dataset
    vehiclesData.put(vehicle, nameToProps);
}
```

Comment: How about having a `List<Vehicle>` where `Vehicle` contains a `List<Model>` and `Model` has a `Map<String, Value>` of the properties.

Comment: Also, you should update this question with the code you're using to populate the map so that people can suggest where the problem might be. As a guess though, it's likely that you need to be adding checks for if keys already exist so that you add to existing maps rather than creating new ones for the top 2 levels of the structure.

Comment: @Tichodroma To be fair most of the other questions he has asked (there have only been four), don't give very detailed answers.

Comment: @NominSim True, but 0% doesn't look very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having seen your code now, the issue is as I hinted at in my comment. e.g. you're creating a new `nameToProps` and a new `propAndVal` every time round the loop rather than checking if there is an existing one that you should be adding to. You want some checks, something like:

```
for( VehicleReportRow vehicleReportRow : unpreparedRows ){
    String vehicle = vehicleReportRow.getVehicle();
    String name = vehicleReportRow.getName();
    String property = vehicleReportRow.getProperty();
    String value = vehicleReportRow.getValue();

    // check if we have an outermost entry for this vehicle type and if not then
    // create one and store it in vehiclesData so that next time we can get the same
    // map for this vehicle type
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>> nameToProps = vehiclesData.get(vehicle);;
    if (nameToProps == null) {
        nameToProps = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>>();
        vehiclesData.put(vehicle, nameToProps);
    }

    // similarly, check if we already have a props to values map for this name
    // and create and store one if not
    HashMap<String,String> propAndVal = nameToProps.get(name);
    if (propAndVal == null) {
        propAndVal = new HashMap<String, String>();
        nameToProps.put(name, propAndVal);
    }

    // store the property and value
    propAndVal.put(property, value);
}
```

If any of this needs explaining further, just let me know.

Comment: ok, one more question: would this also work if the list I get would be completely unordered?

Comment: Yes, the ordering wouldn't matter. e.g. if the `Car, VW, Doors, 4` row was later in the in the list rather than immediately after the `Car, VW, Tires, 4` row the `propAndVal` for the VW would be created when we encounter the first row and the other properties would be put into the correct map regardless of where they occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a hashmap two deep, while your datastructure is three deep. It's like Inception: "We need to go deeper!"

```
{ 
1: "Car" : {
2:     "VW":{ 
3:         "Tires" : "4", "Doors": "4"
       },
       "Porsche":{ 
           "Tires" : "4", "Doors": "2" 
       }
   },
}
```